# Accounting for "missing memory" from sysctl

Tags: osx, memory

I'm on OS X Yosemite, ran this code:

```
unsigned long num_;
sysctl((int[]){CTL_HW, HW_PHYSMEM}, 2, &num_, &len, NULL, 0);
printf("AMT MEM: , %lu\n", num_);
```

and getting back `140735340871680`

Which doesn't make sense: (in IPython 3)

```
In [3]: mem / (1024 ** 3)
mem / (1024 ** 3)
Out[3]: 131070.0
```

Since I have 16 GB of physical memory. I looked at the header for `sysctl.h` and see

```
#define HW_PHYSMEM   5      /* int: total memory */
#define HW_USERMEM   6      /* int: non-kernel memory */
```

So now this really doesn't make sense, I could believe the figure if I passed `HW_USERMEM`, but I specially asked for total memory. What gives?

Did I do some stupid math mistake in the Python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I do some stupid math mistake in the Python code?

Actually, it's your C code that's wrong.

The most direct fix to your code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

int main(void)
{
    int64_t bytes;
    size_t len = sizeof(bytes);
    sysctl({ CTL_HW, HW_PHYSMEM64 }, 2, &bytes, &len, NULL, 0);
    int megs = bytes / 1024 / 1024;
    printf("AMT MEM: %d MiB\n", megs);
}
```

If you use `HW_PHYSMEM` instead, it only works on machines with up to 2 GiB of RAM, since it is storing a count of bytes into a variable that is assumed to be 32 bits in size. The change to a 64-bit argument requires a new `sysctl` value to avoid breaking backwards compatibility. This is why OpenBSD's `sysctl(3)` man page says `HW_PHYSMEM` is obsolete.

I took a few liberties in the code above. I'm doing part of the math in the C code so I can read the output without feeding it through a calculator.¹ I also fixed several integer type warnings and renamed the `num_` variable to `bytes` for clarity.

That code runs fine on some of the BSDs,² but not on OS X or FreeBSD.

On looking at the OS X man page, it seems they want you to use [`sysctlbyname(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html) instead. This works fine here on Yosemite:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

int main(void)
{
    int64_t bytes;
    size_t len = sizeof(bytes);
    sysctlbyname("hw.memsize", &bytes, &len, NULL, 0);
    int megs = bytes / 1024 / 1024;
    printf("AMT MEM: %d MiB\n", megs);
}
```

I have 16 GiB of physical RAM, and it correctly reports 16384 MiB.

If you try that on FreeBSD, though, you get 0 as an answer. A bit of poking around says that it wants `hw.physmem` instead.

And once again we hit a wall, because trying *that* `sysctlbyname` value on OS X gives the sort of bogus results you found.

Therefore, the bottom-line answer is that all of this is highly system-specific. If you need it to be cross-platform, you will need a lot of `#ifdefs`.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. Sorry, I don't have my powers of 2 memorized into the billions yet. :)
2. Tested on OpenBSD 5.5 and NetBSD 6.0.1.

Comment: Much appreciated